# AWS Credentials

Tags: boto3, credentials

I am building a Kubernetes cluster, to start the cluster I need some AWS credentials. One way, I can pass as an environment variable in the Kubernetes deployment file. But I don't want to do that.

Is there any API from AWS, from where I can make an API call to AWS and get the credentials and store it in the environment? Later my application read those from the ENV.

I have been struggling with it for quite a long time. I would really appreciate your thoughts and help.

UPDATE: I solved this issue by using Security Manager

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an IAM Role for your application.
You can use [AWS Secure Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).
Use [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) with an SDK or the CLI to get credentials and inject them into environment variables for your application.